# Is there any open source for Ip Tunnel?

Tags: c, linux, networking, routes

I need one server to receive ip requests from clients(there are not in the same intranet), and I can

route all the response packets to a special gateway server, and then I send the response packages to

clients after some processing. it is like VPN, but I want to do some development based one

opensource project, so i can control it myself.

any suggestion? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/) which is as the name already suggests open source.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the server on the local one as a kind of proxy (or reverse-proxy depending on your viewpoint) and have the clients connect to it.

It depends what protocol you're using, maybe it has explicit proxy capability or you can get an existing proxy program, or just proxy it using a simple socket forwarder program.